# Accessing Azure WebApp with custom URL producing "too many redirects" error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure uses SSL across their webapps and has a cert for *.azurewebsites.net. We have been trying to setup subdomains that point to our webapp but we keep receiving security errors or redirect errors.  So for example, we set an A record that points from subdomain.ourcompany.com to the assigned IP.  Then we set a CNAME record for awverify.subdomain to awverify.webappname.azurewebsites.net.

When you try and access the site, we get a "too many redirects" error.  I don't know if it's relevant but both ourcompany.com and www.ourcompany.com are not hosted on Azure and their A records point somewhere else.

Any idea why we're getting this error?  Note that if we drop the A record and instead create a CNAME record from subdomain.ourcompany.com to webappname.azurewebsites.net, then we receive a SSL certificate error saying that the site isn't trustworthy.  I tried to get around this using cloudflare but to no avail.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article to properly configure custom domains:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

The end result is that you will have the following in your Azure Web App:
[image]

And the following on the DNS registrar side:
[image]

Note that 23.99.65.65 is the VIP of the stamp in which my Azure Web App is hosted, and is displayed at the bottom of the Custom domains and SSL page. It should also be displayed when you resolve (your website name).azurewebsites.net via [digwebinterface.com](http://digwebinterface.com).

Once that is complete, you will have the domain correctly configured and the next step is to purchase a certificate for your site. Once you have purchase the certificate, you can configure it using the following guide:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Note: the reason you are getting an SSL error now is probably because you're using the default SSL cert, which is issued to *.azurewebsites.net. Since this doesn't match your custom domain name, it's going to be an error, although https://(your-site-name).azurewebsites.net should be okay.